# Filter Json object using Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

Platform: C#
IDE: Visual Studio 2010

I am new to Linq and trying to filter a Json object using it. Any suggestions? 
Here is the code:

```
string jsonGetData = objstats.getData_Emp(lblEmp.Text,lblYear.Text);
//JavaScriptSerializer strJsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var lstEmpAnalysis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<empAnalysis>(jsonGetData);
```

Now, from the above lstEmpAnalysis, I need to filter data on first table of the class empAnalysis where one of its index contains countries and show only those countries data being used in filter which is shown below :

```
public class empAnalysis
{
    public List<List<object>> Table { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> Table1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

So, any suggestions?

Input comes in this way :

```
Table 
[0][0] : Abc
[0][1] : India
[0][2] : Engineer
[1][0] : Xyz
[1][1] : UK
[1][2] : Support Engineer
```

And what I want to filter is only the data which contains UK.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here - it would be a lot simpler if you'd give us an example of some input and expected output.

Comment: I suggest you should learn more about Linq.this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx can be a good start.BTW when you deserialize a json object to a .Net object you are no longer working with json .You'd better use strong typed objects rather than generic object so you can write your query based on the type you are working with.

Comment: I hope its clear now...

Comment: I know its possible to check for the data using for loop, but I want to use Linq for learning...

Comment: @HarshKumarSinghi Have a look into Json.Net, particularly the LINQ to Json features...  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always know that second parameter of your table is the country you can do it like this :

```
var items= from item in empAnalysis.Table where item[1]=="UK" select item;
```

Although I always prefer to work with a strong typed object here as I mentioned in my comment :
For example :

```
public class Employee{
       public string Name{get;set;}
       public string Country{get;set;}
       public string JobTitle{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class empAnalysis
{
    public List<Employee> Table { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> Table1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

then we could write :

```
var items= from employee in empAnalysis.Table where employee.Country=="UK" select item;
```

BTW for the purpose of clarity we can do something like this either :

```
var people=from item in empAnalysis.Table select new {
    Title=item[0],
    Country=item[1],
    JobTitle=item[2],
};

var peopleFromUK=from person in people where person.Country=="UK";
```

Although you should be advised that you are getting a list of anonymous typed objects that have Title,Country and JobTitle properties.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a test that I wrote using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) and It passes.

```
[TestFixture]
public class LinqToObjectTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ThereShouldBeOnlyOneListForUK()
    {
        var list = new List<List<object>>
        {
            new List<object>(), 
            new List<object>()
        };

        list[0].Add("Name");
        list[0].Add("UK");
        list[0].Add("Title");


        list[1].Add("Name");
        list[1].Add("NOT UK");
        list[1].Add("Title");
        var query = from item in list where item[1] == "UK" select item;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, query.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: But the above thing is returning the same number of rows including other countries...

Comment: What do you mean by the above thing?

Comment: var items= from item in empAnalysis.Table where item[1]=="UK" select item; // this returns the same number of rows ...

Comment: ok let me run a test to see what's going on

Comment: Ok...Please have a look

Comment: Can you please explain how it works ?

Comment: What do you mean ? How NUnit works or how linq to object works ? Anyway according to code I asserted that there must be only one record that its country was UK and my assertion was satisfied .